# Error in comparing two Intel VTune Amplfier analysis?

Tags: parallel-processing, intel, intel-vtune, intel-parallel-studio

I'm following [this video tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/evaluate-ipsxe-professional-linux) (from Linux) about VTune Amplifier and I've followed everything, but when he compares the two basic analysis there is this error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

All analyses, which are compared must not be opened currently by the Intel VTune Amplifier.

The two analysis `r001hs` is already opened as the tab 'r001hs' indicates. Close it and retry the comparison. Then it will work.